# git excluded files still showing up as untracked

Tags: git

The files I've excluded still show up as untracked. Why? What to do about it? I'm using version 1.9.1

```
$ cat .git/info/exclude
  *.[oa]
  *~
  main
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
     (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

main
main~
main.o
```

Comment: Have you removed them from the staging area via `git rm --cached main~ main.o`?

Comment: @Makoto I've never added them in the first place. If I run `git rm -- cached main` I get `fatal: pathspec 'main' did not match any files`.

Comment: This is very odd. It should be working. I just tried to recreate your problem and as soon as I added the excludes, the files didn't show up as untracked... You don't have a nested git repo right? Having the nested repo could cause something like this to happen (if the exclude is in one level but not another then running `git status` in the one that doesn't have the exclude will show the files as untracked)

Comment: The dashes are too far away from the command.  Git thinks you were looking for files.  Run the command exactly as I've posted it.

Comment: @Makoto If they were in the staging area, the `git status` command would show `Changes to be committed:` and list those files. They wouldn't be under `Untracked`. So I don't think the OP ever staged or tracked these files

Comment: @TheSpurg Thanks for your help -- I have recreated the whole scenario in another directory and saw what the problem was: the lines in `.git/info/exclude` were indented with a few spaces -- as soon as I remove the spaces, everything works; if I put the spaces back in, it breaks.  Sorry, this doesn't show up in my original post -- I haven't been paying attention, not having thought it might be significant. Oddly, emacs by default puts the spaces in when you start editing `.git/info/exclude`.  Thank you for your help once again!

Comment: @dmitry That makes sense. I'm glad you figured it out. It was really bugging me. You should add either an edit to your post or an answer so when anybody comes across this problem themselves, they'll have a solution :)

Comment: @TheSpurg Done -- thank you for your help and advice :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have recreated the whole scenario in another directory and saw what the problem was: the lines in `.git/info/exclude` were indented with a few spaces -- as soon as I remove the spaces, everything works; if I put the spaces back in, it breaks. Something to be careful about.

Comment: For future readers, if you put in-line comments after the path, it will not recognize the path properly either. Maybe also because to put an in-line comment you need a space after the path

Answer (score 0):

I think you have add those file in `.gitignore` after doing changes in them. Those files get stored in cache so you have to rm them from cache using below command:

`git rm --cached filename`

or

`git rm -r --cached .`  // To remove all files

Above command will stop tracking those file but wont delete it from system use.

Comment: The files have never been added to the staging area. If I run this, I get `fatal: pathspec 'main' did not match any files`.